# How to remove dash line from sql output?

Tags: sqlplus

**Query is**

```
select * from User_table;
```

**Output**

```
User_name, address, phone
---------, -------, ------
Ram      , MUMBAI , 444555
John     , Pune   , 999877
```

Want to remove the dash line from output, check below
**Expected output**

```
User_name, address, phone
Ram      , MUMBAI , 444555
John     , Pune   , 999877
```

Comment: @IvanStarostin, what makes you think OP doesn't use sql server?

Comment: That's your query program's presentation behavior, and has nothing to do with SQL itself.

Comment: set underline off but its sql plus behaivor i dont know why you are asking this ?? but the underline doesnt affect your output

Comment: I want to create .csv so need to remove dash line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

**set underline off**

`select * from User_table;`